# Multiply a list of vectors to different matrices conditioned on the vectors' names

Tags: arrays, r, list, matrix, matrix-multiplication

I have a list of 20-length vectors that I would like to multiply each of those with one of three matrices depending on the length vectors' names. Here is my unsuccessful attempt. Please suggest how I improve my code. Any help is much appreciated!

```
for (i in 1:length(List)){
  .$Value=ifelse(names(List) %in% c("a","b","c"),matrixA%*%.$Value,ifelse(names(List) %in% c("d","e"),matrixB%*%.$Value, matrixC%*%.$Value))
}
```

Part of my list   and the matrices are included below.

```html
list(a = structure(c(3, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 10, 0, 0, 1, 1), .Dim = c(20L, 1L)), b = structure(c(2, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 6, 0), .Dim = c(20L, 
1L)))

matrixA <- diag(2,20)
matrixB <- diag(1,20)
matrixC <- diag(4,20)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So... Not sure I understand. But it seems like if the list has name *a, b or c* you want to multiply it to *matrixA*, if it's *d or e* you want to multiply it to *matrixB* and if neither, the values should be multiplied to *matrixC*.

Let's use your example.

```
zz <- list(a = structure(c(3, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 10, 0, 0, 1, 1), .Dim = c(20L, 1L)), b = structure(c(2, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 6, 0), .Dim = c(20L, 
1L)))

matrixA <- diag(2,20)
matrixB <- diag(1,20)
matrixC <- diag(4,20)
```

This is probably not the best solution but it is a simple one. I just made a few tweaks to your ideia so it would work, a matrix needs to be protected by *list()* (because a list is a vector, and ifelse works with vectors) inside an *ifelse()* otherwise you only get the first element. This will return you a list of the results.

```
results <- lapply(seq_along(zz), function(i){
    ifelse(names(zz[i]) %in% c("a","b","c"),list(matrixA%*%zz[[i]]),
            ifelse(names(zz[i]) %in% c("d","e"), list(matrixB%*%zz[[i]]), list(matrixC%*%zz[[i]])))
})
```

I used lapply to apply the sequence to (1 to length of zz) to the defined function. For each *i* the function looks at the name of *i* element *zz* (zz[i] returns the element of the list with its name) and if it satisfies the condition we multiply the content of the *i* element of *zz* (zz[[i]] just returns the content of the *i* element of the list without its name) by a predefined matrix.

This also works and you don't need to protect the matrix using list() which is kinda of a bother.

```
results <- lapply(seq_along(zz), function(i){

    if(names(zz[i]) %in% c("a","b","c")) matrixA%*%zz[[i]] else 
    if(names(zz[i]) %in% c("d","e")) matrixB%*%zz[[i]]
    else matrixC%*%zz[[i]]

})
```

Edit: @akrun answer is way more beautiful and short.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation of the mechanistic.

Answer (score 1):

May be this helps

```
nm1 <- paste0("matrix", toupper(names(lst1)))
Map(crossprod, lst1, mget(nm1))
```